# On button click redirect to different component depend on conditions

Tags: reactjs, router

There is key still it returns false, I have tried following code

```
function godownload() {         
    // platform = {Key:"Internal", Value:""} // for example
    const URL = platform.key === "Internal"? '/component1':'/components2'   
    return   URL
}
```

Comment: Please add more details and improve the question. It is not possible for us to understand with the current information. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit and provide more details like how you are trying to redirect. Are you using [`react-router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) for redirection? Are `/component1` & `/component2` the path names for those components? etc

Comment: Yes I am using react router /component1 and /components 2  are path name, there is key available in platform array but it showing key is undefined so always redirecting to /component2

Comment: `It showing key is undefined` : Is it because you are checking `Key` against `key`?

Comment: No, I checked for same also, still undefined    and  if I checked platform["0"].Key then only it shows value

Comment: @ShitalPadole We need little more details and code. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guide.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need not redirect, but render different component?

```
const Acomponent =() => {

  return "Component A data"
}

const Bcomponent = () => {
  return "Component B data" 
}

const MainComponent = () => {
  const URL = true ? <Acomponent /> : <Bcomponent />;  ->> you get A component
  const URL = false ? <Acomponent /> : <Bcomponent />;  ->> you get B component


  return {URL}  

}
```